# BATCH : I want to extract a "table" surrounded by wordsin a text file and copy this only "table" in a new text file

Tags: batch-file, text, extract

I am really new in Batch and need help... My goal is to read a table of data in a text file an to copy it in antoher text file (output.txt) in the same formate. However, the table in the first text file (let's call it input.txt) is surrounded by other texts.

The advantage is that my table starts with the string "element" and finishes at the end of my input.txt. So that'ts the only part of my input.txt I want to extract and copy in my output.txt.
Another issue is that the string "element" is not directly at the beginning of the first line of my table to extract (there are some spaces).

Here is the text file (input.txt) from which I try to extract my table :

```
Recapitulation des donnees

Nom fichier H46 en entree       : cas.h46Nom fichier sigma en entree     : sigma.txtNom fichier Inp en sortie    : ficRes.inpNom fichier H46 en sortie    : ficRes.h46Nom fichier TXT en sortie    : ficRes.txtEtat limite                     : ELS


Es                              : 200000.00fck                             :     40.00Coefficient d'equivalence       :     13.07Eb                              :  15302.22fctm                            :      3.51types dIFferents de sections    :            1kt                              :      0.40

Caracteristiques de ferraillage a chaque niveau:



AX     AY   PhiX   PhiY   SpX    SpY    EnrX   EnrY     cX     cYType :           115.71  15.71  20.00  20.00 200.00 200.00  74.00  98.00  62.00  86.0015.71  15.71  20.00  20.00 200.00 200.00  74.00  98.00  62.00  86.00

element  type     cas      it      ep       sigaxi     sigaxs     sigayi     sigays     sigbpp     itred    AXI     AXS     AYI      AYS      ATR
  1   1        1        3     0.50     159.13     159.13     -12.08     -12.08      -0.92        0    15.71    15.71    15.71    15.71     0.00
   1   1        2        8     0.50     158.21     158.21     156.09     156.09      -2.00        4    15.71    15.71    16.11    16.11     0.00
   1   1        3       18     0.50     192.73     192.73      74.42      74.42      -2.15       61    21.81    21.81    15.71    15.71     0.00
   1   1        4        7     0.50     192.68     -52.76       0.00       0.00      -7.78      196    35.31    15.71    15.71    15.71     0.00
   1   1        5       21     0.50     192.99     -31.15      30.25     155.89      -9.88      266    42.31    15.71    15.71    34.41     0.00
   1   1        6        9     0.50       0.00       0.00     156.08      -9.88      -4.73      228    15.71    15.71    38.51    15.71     0.00
   1   1        7       30     0.50     193.14      28.28      22.66     155.85      -9.69      225    38.21    15.71    15.71    23.41     0.00
   1   1        8        9     0.50       0.00       0.00     -20.49     155.91      -5.75      118    15.71    15.71    15.71    27.51     0.00
   1   1        9        1     0.50     159.13     159.13       0.00       0.00       0.00        0    15.71    15.71    15.71    15.71     0.00
   1   1       10        1     0.50       0.00       0.00     156.15     156.15       0.00        3    15.71    15.71    16.01    16.01     0.00
   1   1       11        8     0.50     158.51     158.51     155.80     155.80      -1.00        4    15.71    15.71    16.11    16.11     0.00
   1   1       12        8     0.50     158.51     158.51     155.80     155.80      -1.00        4    15.71    15.71    16.11    16.11     0.00
   1   1       13       20     0.50     185.89      -5.65     155.97      -5.36     -11.36      317    34.91    15.71    47.41    15.71     0.00
   1   1       14       20     0.50     185.89      -5.65     155.97      -5.36     -11.36      317    34.91    15.71    47.41    15.71     0.00
   1   1       15        1     0.50     159.13     159.13      95.48      95.48       0.00        0    15.71    15.71    15.71    15.71     0.00
```

Can you help me please

Here is my try :

```bat
@echo off 
set local enable delayed expansion

set "input_file=input.txt"
set "output_file=output.txt"
 
:: Are we in the table?
set "in_table="

:: Temporary file to stock the data
set "temp_file=%temp%\\temp_table.txt"
del "%temp_file%" 2\>nul

:: Go through input.txt
for /f "delims=" %%a in (%input_file%) do (
set "ligne=%%a"

:: Does the line has "element" in it ?
echo !ligne! | find /i "element" >nul
   if !errorlevel! == 0 (
     set "in_table=1"
)

:: If we are in the table, add the line to the temporary file
if defined in_table (
    echo !ligne!>> "%temp_file%"
)
 
)
 
:: Copy the temporary file to the output file
type "%temp_file%" \> "%output_file%"

:: Delete temporary file
del "%temp_file%" 2\>nul

 
endlocal`
```

Comment: The second line has several extra spaces and should read `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`.

Comment: according to your description, it *could* be as easy as `findstr /c:" " input.txt > output.txt`

Answer (score 1):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
rem The following settings for the directories and filenames are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately includes spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "destdir=u:\your results"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q77258106.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"

SET "intable="

(
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%b IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 SET "line=%%b"
 IF DEFINED intable (
  ECHO %%b
 ) ELSE (
  IF "!line:element=!" neq "%%b" SET "intable=o"
 )
)
)>"%outfile%"

GOTO :EOF
```

**Always verify against a test directory before applying to real data.**

Note that if the filename does not contain separators like spaces, then both `usebackq` and the quotes around `%filename1%` can be  omitted.

You would need to change the values assigned to `sourcedir` and `targetdir` to suit your circumstances. The listing uses a setting that suits my system.

I deliberately include spaces in names to ensure that the spaces are processed correctly.

I used a file named `q77258106.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Produces the file defined as `%outfile%`

First, ensure `intable` is set to *nothing*, which makes it `undefined`.

For each line inn the file, assign the line to `%%b` and then to `line`.

If `intable` is defined, write out the line in `%%b`, otherwise see whether `line` with the string `element` replaced by *nothing* is the same as `%%b`. If it is not equal (`neq`) then `set` the variable `intable` to *something* (anything; the point is that `intable` will become defined and the code will then execute `echo %%b` for the remaining lines)

See `set /?` from the prompt or thousands of SO items for documentation on the `!var:string=replacement!` syntax

The entire `for` statement is then (enclosed in parentheses) and redirected to the output file, which will create a new file or overwrite any existing file.

Hence there's no need to use a temporary file or delete any existing output file.

You should note that in your code, within a block statement `(a parenthesised series of statements)`, `REM` statements rather than the broken-label remark form (`:: comment`) should be used because labels terminate blocks, confusing `cmd`. `::` is a broken label because you cannot reach `::` with a `goto`, but it's a label nonetheless.

A second problem with your logic is that the test for `element` is executed *before* the test whether `in_table` is defined, so the line containing `element` will set `in_table` and then the line will be `echo`ed as `in_table` is now set. You need to conduct the `element`-presence test *after* `in_table` is tested.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, as your `input.txt` file appears to use spaces in the table, rather than horizontal tabs, you could just do it like this:

```bash
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions
Set "input_file=input.txt"
Set "output_file=output.txt"
Set "LNr=" & For /F "Delims=:" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe
 /RNIC:" *element\>" "%input_file%"') Do If Not Defined LNr Set /A LNr = %%G - 1
If Defined LNr (
    %SystemRoot%\System32\more.com +%LNr% "%input_file%" 1>"%output_file%")
```

Essentially, it uses `findstr.exe` to retrieve the line number of the first matching line, (beginning with zero or more spaces followed by the word `element`). This line number is then used, (after subtracting `1` from it using `Set /A`), with the `more.com` utility.